# Set number of visible children in Android Gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I have 2 galleries in my app.
App must support various screen sizes.

I need first gallery to have 4 items visible...it can scroll left and right ofcourse.
Second gallery has 3 visible items all the time.

Is it possible to set number of visible children in gallery?
Or the only way is to set layout params of children? That seems to bo too complicated, because of various screen sizes.

Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me is via LayoutParams and setting width of gallery item.